# Write error log file in seperate folder in BizTalk orchestration

Tags: error-handling, biztalk, error-log, biztalk-orchestrations

How can we handle the error inside of BizTalk orchestration and write the log file in separate folder by using the scope and expression components in BizTalk orchestration?

Is there any possible ways to write the error file without viewing the event manager?

Comment: thanks for all. I had found a solution to write the error content in txt file in desired location. by the use of expression node the catched error can be writen in text file. there is lot of posible ways to write the error in Log or Database..... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling inside a BizTalk orchestration is quite trivial. You can add an exception block to any non-atomic scope to be able to catch any exceptions (e.g. General Exception, System.Exception, DivideByZeroException, etc...

Your question actually has several possible answers.

The first option would actually to be to question your approach.
Is writing the error to a log file really necessary? Is it perhaps sufficient to be able to System.Diagnostics.Trace the error using a listener like DebugView for example?
An example on this approach can be found here: http://dickvdbrink.github.io/c%23/2015/01/09/CSharp-Logging-using-Trace-and-DebugView.html

Option 2 is what you might be looking for:

1. Create a new generic error schema
2. Using a C# static helper class, create a new instance of the schema, populating it with the necessary fields you fill in from the exception/innerexception.
3. Send the instance to a folder using a send shape and the binding of your choice (direct, specify later, etc...)

Option 3 would be taking it one step further: Implement Failed Message Routing in your orchestration. By default this exists only in receive ports and send ports, but you can mimic the behavior in your own orchestration. The only thing you need to do is to write the error to the context of the message and the ErrorType to "FailedMessage".
I found an example of this approach here: http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2006/11/01/Failed-Message-Routing-and-Failed-Orchestration-Routing-in-BizTalk-2006.aspx

Option 3 would be most generic and viable in my opinion as option 1 would most likely require you to build in DEBUG mode and option 2 is not a very generic/good option.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if an error happens, you can do anything you want but...

**You should always use the Event Log**.  Writing event to a log *file* is quite bad practice.

This article describes how to properly use the Event Log from a BizTalk app: [Logging In BizTalk Apps using Event Logs: Good Practices](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35939.logging-in-biztalk-apps-using-event-logs-good-practices.aspx)

You don't always have to create you own Log, just a custom Source.